# ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC problem redirecting after signing in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-authentication

I have recently been experiencing an issue when attempting to login on the web app that I am working on, I did not modify the Startup.cs file and it used to work last time when I used it, but now when I am trying to log in it redirects me back to the Login page, although signing in succeeds

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, 
    model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    // return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
}
```

it hits the RetirectToAction, but I am sent back to Login Page, also I see two statuses in the network console, 200 and 302 which should be ok

Just a little update, after trying different things it looks like the signInManager does not sign me in at all

Startup.cs

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<AORContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AORContext>();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Default User settings.
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

        });

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Default Password settings.
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            //options.Cookie.Name = "YourAppCookieName";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
            // ReturnUrlParameter requires 
            //using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
            //options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
            //options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
            // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                             .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                             .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: This question is a bit vague at this stage.  Can you clarify what is happening versus what you expect to happen? What do you think the problem is?

Comment: I expect to be redirected to home page once The application logs me in and I think the problem is the the sign in manager does not sign me in although it says so, I think it might have to do with the authentication cookie as it’s no longer saved for some reason

Comment: The `lockoutOnFailure` param looks promising.. wonder if your account got locked out for some reason? Might be worth checking this user in the db if you can...

Comment: Checked, and it is not that, I also tried with different accounts

Comment: Share us your `Startup.cs`.

Comment: try to run `Update-Package` in `Package Manager Console`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this feels more like a hack than anything but I got it work by redirecting the action back to itself with a flag. And if the flag is set, redirect to the actual target page:

```
// GET: LoginWithToken
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("LoginWithToken")]
public async Task<ActionResult> LoginWithToken(string token = null, bool tokenLoginSuccess = false)
{
    // redirect
    if (tokenLoginSuccess)
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

    // set cookie
    await schoolLoginService.SignInWithToken(this.HttpContext, token);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWithToken), new { tokenLoginSuccess = true });
}
```